# Setting the correct width for each individual table column?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem setting width(s) of each individual column within a table. I have created a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgGbt/) which shows the table and each of it's columns. I have stated what percentage of width I want for each column, but as you will see when you open up the fiddle, the width of those columns do not match the desired percentages that I have set for each column width.

Are there any visible errors in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables columns will size(w) by the content and only slim to the lowest possible width. I'm not sure if there's a good way to do this with a traditional table.

You may want to try using div's to construct the table which will give you the ability to use overflow:scroll/hidden properties.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see browser tries to make it as close to your percentage values as possible. However keep in mind that it will always make column wide enough to show its cells content - for example it will always be wide enough to keep word "Number" visible even you've set it to be 3% only.